# Google Drive API get edit url (aka alternateLink) for file with PHP SDK

Tags: php, google-drive-api

- I've setup my project to use the [PHP SDK for the Google Drive
  API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started)
- I'm using a refresh token to authenticate a **user** via OAuth2 (not 
  using a service account, if it matters)
- I am getting a list of files from a specific folder with this
  function:

.

```
function getDriveFilesForFolder($app){
    // Get the API client and construct the service object.
    $client = getClient($app); // function that gets an authorized client instance
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    // we only want files from a specific folder
    $q="'".$app->constants->get('GOOGLE_DOCS_MAIN_FOLDER_ID')."' in parents";
    $optParams = array(
         'q' => $q
    );
    $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
    if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
        echo "No files found.<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Files:<br>";
        foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
            //var_dump($file);
            echo '<br><br>';
            echo $file->getName()." (".$file->getId().") ";
        }
    }
}
```

This works and prints out the list of file names and their ids.

---

- Now I need to get an editable link for each file and have that print
  out as well.
- From my searching, what I want is the `alternateLink` which is
  [documented here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource-representations) for the Rest endpoint
- I see no function in `Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile` or
  `Google_Collection` which it extends that will return the
  `alternateLink`.

**How do I get the `alternateLink` value from the `$file` object in my code using the PHP SDK?**

---

**Worth mentioning**

- These files are pre-existing and not created with the PHP SDK

Answer (score 0):

The best I've been able to come up with so far is looping over the file objects and using their ids to get the file metadata with cURL using the same access token from the authenticated php client like this:

```
private function getFileMetaData($files){
    /**
     *  the php sdk doesnt seem to have a way to get the alternate url (edit url) for a file
     *  so we'll have to loop over the files and get their metadata using cURL
     */
    $metadataArray=[];
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $restEndpoint="https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/".$file->getId();
        $ch = curl_init($restEndpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Bearer '.$this->client->getAccessToken()['access_token']
        ));
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $metadataArray[]=$data;
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    return $metadataArray;
}
```

This works but sure doesn't feel like the right way to do this.

Posting this and leaving this open, hopefully someone will know the right way.